# What JSON validator does VScode use?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, static-analysis

I really like the JSON validator that vscode has. It catches errors that a lot of editors don't, so I really want to use it in my pre commit tests. To do that, I was hoping there was an npm equivalent of it.

Let's say I'm linting this JSON file.

```json
{
  "a": "b",
  "b": "c",
  "c": "d",
}
```

It has a trailing comma, and that's not allowed. However, [jsonlint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonlint), which appears to be the most popular npm json linter gives the error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 4:
...b": "c", "c": "d",}
---------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', got '}'
```

Which could take me forever to track down, whereas vscode:

```
Trailing comma json(519) [4,11]
```

That's much easier to read.

Comment: I think they use their own json validation. The syntax file can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/json/syntaxes/JSON.tmLanguage.json).

Comment: @HaaLeo Is there like a shell command I can use to validate a file?

Comment: I am not aware of one, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Trailing commas for JSON was introduced in ES5. Depending on your configuration, you may or may not catch the error above.

You can add a [jsconfig.json or tsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig), depending on the language you are using.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```